# Unable to extend logical volume on RHEL Appliance

Tags: linux, redhat, disk-space-utilization

**The Issue**

I am facing an issue while upgrading an RHEL virtual appliance for the CA/Broadcom API Gateway

The issue shows its face during the upgrade from 9.3 to 9.4 where the 2GB /tmp directory is too small to extract the platform patch

Naturally, the next step was to increase the /tmp directory to allow for a successful extraction - following the documentation found here:

https://techdocs.broadcom.com/content/broadcom/techdocs/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/layer7-api-management/api-gateway/9-3/reference/virtual-appliance-deployment-best-practices/virtual-appliance-configuration/increase-size-of-virtual-disk.html

**I have done all of this without issue:**

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
Select Option N to add a new partition
Select Option P to set the new partition as the primary
Specify "1" to set the partition number
Press <Enter> to accept the default starting cylinder
Press <Enter> to accept the default ending cylinder
Select Option T to change the partition type
Specify "8e" to change the type to "Linux LVM"
Select Option W to write the changes to disk.
Initialize the new disk partition: pvcreate /dev/sdb1
Add a physical volume to an existing volume group: vgextend vg00 /dev/sdb1
```

**Where it breaks:**

My issue comes in here: `lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_tmp /dev/sdb1`

The "-r" flag in `lvextend` (resize2fs) resizes the actual filesystem and that is the portion that fails

When looking at `lvscan`, the actual volume was extended successfully (original 2GB + additional 10GB from extra disk = 12GB) on the /lv_tmp

The problem is the following: although the logical volume has been extended, the file system did NOT resize successfully (so effectively `lvscan` reports 12GB and `df -h` states only 2GB)

I just get a `fsadm: Resize ext3 Failed. fsadm failed: 1`

**Expected Outcome:**

Usable space should be increased to 12GB after extending the original 2GB with another 10GB

Comment: And what happens if you just run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_tmp` by itself?

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I have another change slot tomorrow evening, so will only be able to try this out then. Will respond ASAP. Appreciated

Comment: Hi there @bodgit this did the trick. For some reason running it along with lvextend causes issues at the client, whereas doing it in the lab succeeds without a problem. Probably better doing it separately anyway. Had to run it as `resize2fs /dev/vg00/lv_tmp` though. Would send you a bottle of wine if I could

Comment: Glad it worked. I think I've always run them as separate steps, partly through ignorance of the `-r` option, mostly so I can verify the LV is extended before then growing the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing `ext[234]` filesystems has some prerequisites, most importantly: the filesystem being in a clean state. If `lvextend` (calling `fsadm`, in turn calling `resize2fs`) will not show you the specific error, check it manually:

```
e2fsck -fn /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_tmp
```

Typically, resize2fs would explicitly tell you what you need to to before the resize operation:

```
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_tmp
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_tmp' first
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I have another change slot tomorrow evening, so will only be able to try this out then. Will respond ASAP. Appreciated

Comment: As mentioned above. Running `resize2fs /dev/vg00/lv_tmp` on its own fixed the issue. Many thanks